# Is there a better way to group words for the Regexp Or operator?

Tags: regex, vba, com

When using regular expressions in VBA, (Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5) I often find myself looking for one of several words as part of a larger pattern. My usual way of doing this is to use parentheses around each word, separated by the vertical bar `|` OR operator.

For example:  `((mitt)|(bat)|(ball)|(mask))`

The final set of parentheses around the entire group lets me find out which word matched. The inner parentheses is to make the OR work on each entire word, not just the first/last letter of a word.

However, I end up with a bunch of worthless submatches -- one for each word enclosed in parentheses. Is there a better approach to grouping "words" for the OR operator?

Comment: I dont have much experience with vba but you shouldnt need the internal parenthesis at all. The `|` split the contents of the outer parenthesis. If you wanted you could add `?:` to the start of each parenthesis group to not capture that group in your match results.

Comment: The outer group can be made optional, or inner groups may be removed - it all depends on what you need.

Comment: Thanks Marie & Wiktor. Marie, is the ?: construct supported in Microsoft's implementation? Based on the documentation I'm looking at, it isn't. But I could be missing something...

Comment: A non-capturing group is supported in ECMAScript regex.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 *does* support things like non-capturing groups (?:) and look-ahead/negative look-ahead. The documentation I was looking at was either old or incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the inner parenthesis:

```
(mitt|bat|ball|mask)
```

Is enough. See [Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I've been doing it the hard way for years. Glad I asked.